# roscreate-qt-pkg and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a ROS-Qt package with the command

```
rosrun qt_create roscreate-qt-pkg mypackage
```

and am able to compile it with rosmake and run it. In order to edit the project in  Eclipse I have run:

```
make eclipse-project
```

but that results in Eclipse not knowing about Qt. Who can help me to get this working?

Regards,

Frits

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27956/roscreate-qt-pkg-and-eclipse/) by [frits.vanevert](https://answers.ros.org/users/1817/frits.vanevert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved. I added some folders to the include path and everything works just fine now.

---

Originally posted by [frits.vanevert](https://answers.ros.org/users/1817/frits.vanevert/) with karma: 16 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0